# I don't understand clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, clearinterval

I have play and skip buttons for JSON array working fine:

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Fetch the initial image
    fetchImage(index);

    // Event listeners
    $("#play").click(function() { fetchImage(next); setInterval(function() { fetchImage(next); }, 1000); return false;});
    $("#stop").click(function() { clearInterval(xxx); return false;});
    $("#prev").click(function() { fetchImage(prev); return false;});
    $("#next").click(function() { fetchImage(next); return false;});
});
```

xxx should preferably be a variable I read. setInterval() returns a value. I've read several examples. I have not been successful.

Test page: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_16.php

JSON thing: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_cogo_16.txt

Source: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.txt

Comment: You must first name your `setInterval` like so: `var newInterval = setInterval(function(){...}`.  Then you can `clearInterval` with xxx being `newInterval` - I learned from here:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: We didn't understand it either, but that's what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) is for, to look up functions we don't understand so we can learn how they work.

Comment: "I don't understand ____" is not a question.

Comment: adeneo: Yes. I did read the MDN pages before asking here. The syntax was too much to grasp for me.

Comment: naomik: Certainly true. Perhaps "I don't understand ____" is not a cool way of naming posts. I'd like to take this opportunity though to point out that most questions on Stack Overflow are not formulated as questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name your interval first to be able to clear it.  Here's what I would do to your code:

```
    var newInterval;
    // Event listeners
    $("#play").click(function() { 
        fetchImage(next); 
        newInterval = setInterval(function() { 
            fetchImage(next); 
        }, 1000); 
        return false;
    });

    $("#stop").click(function() { 
        clearInterval(newInterval); 
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Best to assign the var at the top, if the user clicks stop before play then `newInterval` will be undefined

Comment: Thank you very much. Your (topmost) code works like a charm in all browsers. It was so well formatted and in line with my existing code so I tried this first.

Comment: @carl that's right,  Thank you.  I'll get rid of the lower code.  ole no problem!  I'm glad I could help

Comment: So very cool to have those four buttons working. I'm now trying to get the JSON array to PHP. I'm not even sure if this is a JSON array: http://flamencopeko.net/icons_ajax.php though.

Comment: That is not "naming the interval", it already *has* a numeric identifier... You're simply storing the number in a variable instead of throwing it away.

Comment: @darien, yes for those of us who want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the setInterval function to a variable

`var interval = setInterval(function () {});`

`clearInterval(interval)`

I am assuming that is what you are after.

Comment: Yes. Done. Works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

you gave the answer yourself

"it returns a value"

so let it return an alias for a value, a so called variable, ideally you declare it before so it doesnt throw undefined exception when you try to clear it an no #play was clicked befre

```
var xxx;
... 
$("#play").click(function() { fetchImage(next);xxx=setInterval(function() { fetchImage(next); }, 1000); return false;});
...
clearInterval(xxx)...
```

Comment: Indeed. I just couldn't get the syntax right. I'm especially bad with jQuery. Problem is solved now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used one of those "take a number" devices which extrude numbered slips of paper?

The return value from `setInterval()` is like a "Repeating Task ID#".

You shouldn't care how big the number is, but you **should** store it somewhere, and then you can pass it back into `clearInterval()` to tell the system which task to stop running.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant by "I don't understand ____", ;) but I love this one too. Thanks.